# How do linked tables in MS Access works?

Tags: vba, ms-access, linked-tables, adp

Need few inputs on how **Linked tables** work in MS Access . previously we have MS Access forms as front end and SQL server as backend and we used ADP project.

But , now our goal is to **convert this ADP to linked tables and accdb project**.

I have **searched** a lot over internet for linked tables and could find only few information over it .

I **would like to know how it is different from ADP**.

I have already created a new ACCDB project and imported all my forms and linked database objects by using linked tables manager

But , **when i try to do lookup for a certain table , it does not work , it is showing an exception that table is not found**

Can any **one share a piece of code** to see how to access a linked table from VB .

Comment: 1) You've tagged this 'vb.net', but VB.NET doesn't seem to come into it; 2) show us the code

Comment: You still haven't provided the code that's not working for you.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston The problem is i worked on only ADP and not sure of linked tables. I could not find any code on internet to begin working with linked tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked tables are similar to local tables but their source is not within the local access database. You might

- Link an Excel sheet as linked table
- MSSQL as linked table
- MySQL as linked table (ODBC connection)
- and so on..

after linking, the tables become standard table like any other tables in your Access project. Only different would be, the linked tables will be refreshed at every startup (or at a certain ODBC time interval)

You have mentioned ADP and then linked tables in ACCDB, i guess you want to move from an older Access version to a newer one?

From a concept point of view, there shouldn't be any problem. In the background (VBA) you would either use DAO or ADODB (mostly DAO ist simple and handy)

back to your question.

- Make sure all of the tables & queries have been imported
- Make sure all linked tables have been refreshed.
- produce us few more code or screenshot so we can help you